Can you rely on constant jump starts?
I was having some start up issues which were most likely to do with battery or alternator.  Regardless of the cause I found that I could use my jump starter to get the car moving on every occasion and whenever I stalled.  As I don’t use the car often and didn’t have the time or money to investigate I just kept using the jump starter.
Whatever the cause was, if repeated jump starts was working and you can’t really get it repaired, can you just keep doing this for a long time or indefinitely?
Correct me if I’m wrong, but if the alternator is bad or there is parasitic drain this will work, but the battery will eventually give in and it will no longer respond to jump starts so you can rely on the jump starter until this happens?
Thanks.

Yes, but with caveats. I now people who have done this, i.e. just used a portable jump starter instead of fixing an issue, when the issue was too expensive or complex to fix and the car was destined for the junk heap.
The battery doesn't respond to jump starts, the jump starts will work whether or not the battery is viable. The battery has to work just so far as forming part of a circuit, whether or not it can hold a charge is immaterial to a certain extent. Jump starting a car doesn't damage or wear a battery, what does damage a battery is undercharging, if you don't get whatever is wrong fixed your battery will eventually be scrap. But, as you will be jumping it that doesn't fundamentally matter, as the alternator will be supplying all the power you need. This assumes your alternator is working properly, if it isn't you can jump it to start it but if you battery is shot and your alternator is shot your car will quit as soon as you take the cables as there's no power to keep the engine running. If you can jump it and it stays running then your alternator sounds like it's fine.
The caveats to this are:

If you jump it wrong you can damage your car, so don't get careless
If your engine stalls your battery won't have the charge to restart your car, which can be either very inconvenient or potentially put you at risk, so keep that in mind
Running with a bad battery will put extra strain on your alternator. The lower your battery voltage is the harder your alternator has to work, if your battery is shot your alternator will always be working at high capacity, which will shorten its life

Takeaways here are:

As your alternator seems to be working fine you may be able to fix this with a new battery, which is cheap way to solve your problem and would be safer and more convenient
Running with a bad battery will strain your alternator, which will be much more expensive to replace than a battery, so running with a bad battery  is a false economy

